# $n$ Tennis players took part in the one-round table tennis tournament $(n \geq 3)$. We say that player $A$ is better than player $B$, if ...

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

$n$ Tennis players took part in the one-round table tennis tournament $(n \geq 3)$. We say that player $A$ is better than player $B$, if $A$ won $B$ or there is such a player $C$, that $A$ won $C$, and $C$ won $B$. For what $n$ in the tournament could it be that each player is better than everyone else? There are no draws in tennis.

I proved that $n = 3k$ is suitable, I also learned how to make an example for $n = 5$, I assume that $n = 3k + 2$ is suitable, but I cannot prove it, it is also not clear what to do if $n = 3k + 1$.

Comment: What is a "one-round tournament"?  Perhaps if you show the $n=5$ example I can better understand the tournament format?

Comment: one-round tournament is when everyone has played exactly one time with each

Comment: Ah, thanks, what I usually call a "round-robin" tournament then.  :)

Comment: I am _very_ curious about your $n=3k$ solution, especially since I found an $n=2k+1$ solution!  Can you please post your $n=3k$ solution?  (Also is your $n=5$ solution same as my $n=odd$ solution?)

Comment: @antkam Presumably, divide the people into three equal groups labeled Rock, Paper and Scissors.

Comment: @MikeEarnest maybe I'm missing something obvious, but how does a Rock beat (directly or indirectly) another Rock?  I can see this happening if, among the Rocks, you use something like my $n=odd$ solution, but then if each of the 3 groups (no need for equal size) are odd numbered, then the total number is odd and you could have just used my solution to begin with.

Comment: Good point! Perhaps OP was mistaken and it is only possible for odd $n$. @antkam

Comment: @MikeEarnest - Your RPS idea does imply this: If some even $n$ is feasible, then any larger even $N > n$ is also feasible, because you can always divide $N-n$ into two odd groups and use my solution for each.

Comment: @Yaroslav - I think I have a full solution, but just yesterday I got duped into helping someone with a contest question, and that left a really bad taste.  Can you tell me what is the source of this problem?  If it is e.g. homework I can give some hints instead.

Comment: if you take two triangles and connect them, you get an example on n = 6.

Comment: Yes, this is homework

Comment: @Yaroslav then you have the full solution.  :)  But next time pls mention it's homework first so people can give hints instead.  My Answer says all odd $n$ are feasible, and $n=4$ is infeasible.  Further $n=2$ is obviously infeasible, and you yourself showed $n=6$ is feasible.  One of my comments above is a hint on how to generalize from any even $n$ (e.g. $6$) to all higher even numbers, so that covers everything.  Do you agree, or do you need more hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partial solution...  specifically:

**Claim A:** Any odd $n$ is feasible.

**Claim B:** $n = 4$ is infeasible.

**Proof of A:** Arrange the players in a circle and number them $0, ..., n-1$, and let $i$ beat $i+1, i+3, ..., i+n-2$.  All arithmetic is modulo $n$.

First of all, this assignment is consistent: For any $i \neq j$, if $j = i + odd$ (i.e. $i$ beats $j$) then $i = j + even$ (i.e. $j$ does not beat $i$).

Next, clearly $i$ beats all the $i+odd$ directly, but since each $j$ beats $j+1$, $i$ also indirectly beats all the $i+odd+1$, i.e. all the $i+even$.

**Proof of B:** Among the $n=4$ players, clearly nobody can beat everyone or be beaten by everyone.  Since each plays $3$ games, that means each must win only $1$ or $2$ games.  Since there are $6$ games total, the only way to do this is if two players $W,X$ win twice each and two other players $Y,Z$ win once each.  But consider the match between $Y,Z$ and without loss assume $Y$ beats $Z$.  This is $Y$'s only win, and $Z$ beats only $1$ person (e.g. $W$), so $Y$ does not directly nor indirectly beat the other person (e.g. $X$).